# Problems with including Bootstrap to SpringMVC project via WebJars

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I've tried to use Bootstrap in my SpringMVC project:
[link to GitHub repo](https://github.com/mc-suchecki/Finager)

Unfortunately, CSS files are not visible. The browser is throwing errors in the console like this:

`GET http://localhost:8080/finager/webjars/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)`

I think pom.xml has proper configuration, because I am able to view included WebJars (Bootstrap and JQuery) in Eclipse under Java Resources -> Libraries -> Maven Dependencies. I've also set path in servlet-context.xml like this (last line):

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

I think this line is correct, because Tomcat no longer says that it don't know how to handle request starting with '/webjars/. All tutorials that I've found lists only these steps, and I couldn't find any useful information on the Internet. I've spent whole day on this, as I am new to Spring development , so any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specifying the location this way will fix the issue for you(note the `classpath:`) :

```
<resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

Also, you appear to have jquery 1.8.2 in your path, so the url should be along these lines:

```
http://localhost:8080/finager/webjars/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js
```

Here is a good reference - https://spring.io/blog/2014/01/03/utilizing-webjars-in-spring-boot

Comment: This and checking Bootstrap version fixed the issue! Thank you!

Comment: When using Spring Boot to build Spring MVC apps, Spring Boot will automatically add the "/webjars/**" resource configuration for you.

Comment: One can add this via code:
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/")
        .setCachePeriod(604800);

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring boot it is done automatically check the WebMvcAutoConfiguration class

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java

```
    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };
```